# Automatically inversing relations in Doctrine2.x

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

In Doctrine 1.2, you used to be able to automatically define a collection on the opposite side of a relation by defining it only on the owning side.  The other side needn't know about the class that was relating to it.

Is it possible to do this in Doctrine 2.x without having to create a variable and mapping on the owned side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it probably is allowed, I woudn't do that. Take this example:

1) Category has Many products. So you fetch a page with most-sold products and show its Category name; you must have that relation on Products side.

2) Let's say that Category can be deleted only if there are no products. So you would have a method:

```
public function isDeletable()
{
  return count($this->getProducts())==0 ;
}
```

I am sure better examples could be made, I just made it quick&dirty. My suggestion would be to always put both sides because you will never know when it will become handy, and it also makes consistency in your entities.